# @type in JSON response

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, generics

I have a Generic class:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({/*my classes here*/})
@XmlRootElement
public class Response<T> implements Serializable{ /*fields*/}
```

When the JSON response returns from the server, it comes with a @type information in it. I want to remove this from the response. Any help would be appreciated.

Response looks like the following:

```
{"response":{"@type":"myType","email":"abc@abc.com","firstName":"A","id":"3","lastName":"B","password":"12345","userName":"user"}}
```

I hope this is not a Jackson or Jersey bug.

Comment: I'm guessing this never got solved, I've run into the same issue I need to use '@XmlSeeAlso' but I don't want the '@type' output but have no idea how to stop it from being added to the output?

Answer (score 1):

This normally shows up because your `Response` class is annotated with `@JsonTypeInfo`.  If you don't want it then you can remove this annotation, although bear in mind that then you will not have any information about the type you are returning.

Comment: I think you are talking about @XmlSeeAlso, but if I don't put it, it does not parse at all. I don't want any type info. Thanks..

Comment: Can you post your complete `Response` class here?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well, but this question is similar and the answer works [Binding a Generic Java Class to a JSON using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422545/binding-a-generic-java-class-to-a-json-using-jaxb)

It's a fairly simple answer although I'd struggle to explain why or how it works and doesn't cause the mapping to occur.